# how I can add or upload picture or photo to this site (stackexchange) in a comment?

Tags: discussion

how I can add or upload picture or photo to this site (stackexchange) in a comment ??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asking about functionality of the stack exchange network.  This question might be suitable for meta, but the correct answer may be a lot simpler than that (you can't put an image in a comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do so by creating a link to the image and posting that. Preferably using Imgur.

It should be noted that you will also need the required reputation to post comments (on questions and answers other than your own), which is currently 50 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to add inline images in comments, the answer is probably [**no, not for any site in the StackExchange network.**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85498/is-it-possible-to-add-images-to-comments) It is easy to abuse and goes against the idea of comments as short requests for clarification. Useful information should always be in questions and answers themselves; comments are treated like red-headed stepchildren.

IIRC this feature exists in SE-like sites like Unity Answers, so it's not like the software doesn't support it. It is however a feature that would go against some pretty fundamental philosophies of StackExchange, so I wouldn't even bother asking for this.